# Formal proof for the limit of $\frac{\tanh(x)-1}{e^{-2x}}$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, limits-without-lhopital, epsilon-delta

Formal proof for the limit of $\frac{\tanh(x)-1}{e^{-2x}}$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$.

**So far**

Keep in mind I have to use the definition for a limit. I.e for this would be a proof for the limit at $\infty$ with a finite value (I have checked this to be $-2$). I would have to use the definition that states $\lim_{x \ \to \  \infty} f(x) = L \Leftrightarrow 
  \forall \ \epsilon>0\; (\exists \ \delta : (\;x>\delta\implies |f(x) - L|\leq\epsilon)).
$ i.e I start off by by finding that $$\left | \frac{\tanh{x}-1}{e^{-2x}}-(-2) \right | \iff \left | \frac{2}{1+e^{2x}} \right |$$ Or just
$\frac{2}{1+e^{2x}}$ since we will assume $\epsilon >0$. *Now* I would have to to start my proof and this is where I struggle.

I know that
"for alle $\epsilon>0$ let $\delta=\frac{2}{1+e^{2\epsilon}}>0$ and $x>\delta>0$....."

*Remark: I know we use $N,M,K$ and not $\delta$ normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on feedback in comments I will add reasonable detail in the answer. Some of it may be skipped by those already well versed.

---

The definition of $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) =L$ requires us to show that for every $\epsilon >0$ we can find a corresponding $\delta>0$ such that the inequality $|f(x) - L|<\epsilon $ holds whenever $x>\delta$.

But this **does not mean** that we start with inequality $|f(x) - L|<\epsilon$ and manipulate it according to valid laws to transform it into "$x>\text{something} $" and then put $\delta=\text{something} $. This approach is what I call *solving an inequality* and I request readers never to do this while giving formal proofs of limits.

Instead what really needs to be done is to find an expression, say $g(x) $, which is very simple in form and satisfies $|f(x) - L|<g(x) $ and then try to solve $g(x) <\epsilon$. The simple form of $g(x) $ is needed to make this solving part trivial.

---

Here the desired limit $L=-2$ and we need to use the fact that $e^x>1+x$ if $x>0$ in order to find a suitable $g(x) $. By using it you get $$|f(x) - L|=\frac{2}{1+e^{2x}}<\frac{2}{2x+2}=\frac{1}{x+1}<\frac{1}{x}$$ Now the rightmost expression is less that $\epsilon$ if $x>1/\epsilon$. Thus we can take $\delta$ to be any number greater than or equal to $1/\epsilon$ (in particular $\delta=1/\epsilon$ works).

Essentially you have to do a very gross estimation of $|f(x) - L|$ by $g(x) $. The goal to have a very very simple form for $g(x)$ and you don't need to worry however gross the estimation by $g(x)$ is.

Comment: "Whenever you are using definition of limit, do not try to solve inequalities" What do you exactly mean by this? I think this is my mistake. I am having a hard time seeing how you got the inequality for $x$.

Comment: The inequality $e^x\geq 1+x$ (equality only when $x=0$) is a defining property of exponential function.

Comment: Yes I see. But shouldn't we then just pick a $\delta$ (looking at the other answer because I am in the middle of that approac) to be what? Wouldn't it be $\delta = \frac{2}{e^{2 \epsilon}+1}$ and no need for maximum of the 2 since this will always be bigger than 0 since $\epsilon > 0$

Comment: @user879295: that $\delta$ won't work. The point of other answer is not about finding an explicit $\delta$, but saying that a desired $\delta$ exists.

Comment: Ok I am really in trouble then. I thought that $\bigg|\frac{-2e^{2x}}{e^{2x}+1}-(-2)\bigg|=\bigg|2-\frac{2e^{2x}}{e^{2x}+1}\bigg|=\frac{2}{e^{2x}+1}$ means that you can pick the $\delta$ to be the result after computing $\left |f(x)-L  \right |$ AND THEN in your proof work backwards to show that this works. Would you please show me how to do this from start to finish because I am really misguided I see now.

Comment: @user879295: this will take up some time. Wait for the update.

Comment: Thank you so much. If you can only keep it to the elementary inequalities i.e the exponential one etc. I would really appreciate it as I am quite new at analysis and looking for generel approaches.

Comment: @user879295: see updated answer.

Comment: I follow you untill the gross estimation part. I am unsure on how to even proceed from such a point as We have that $\delta = 1/\epsilon$. Do we just have to show that $x>\delta = 1/\epsilon$? How do we finish the proof?

Comment: My approach wouldve been to show that our delta is smaller than $x$ by working backwards but that does not see to satisfy this approach.

Comment: @user879295: the proof is finished when you have found an explicit expression for $\delta$ in terms of $\epsilon $ or you have shown (via some logical argument) the existence of such a $\delta$ without explicitly finding it. The process of getting $\delta$ should be based on a valid argument which shows that it will work as per definition of limit.

Comment: @user879295: in my answer it should be obvious that if $\delta=1/\epsilon$ and $x>\delta$ then $1/x<\epsilon $ and then $|f(x) - L|<\epsilon $. But this part need not be written in a proof (unless some professor demands it) as it should be made obvious from the process of finding $\delta$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\tanh(x)-1}{e^{-2x}}=\bigg(\frac{e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}+1}-1\bigg)\cdot e^{2x}=\frac{-2e^{2x}}{{e^{2x}+1}}$$

So $$\bigg|\frac{-2e^{2x}}{e^{2x}+1}-(-2)\bigg|=\bigg|2-\frac{2e^{2x}}{e^{2x}+1}\bigg|=\frac{2}{e^{2x}+1}$$

Now if $\varepsilon>0$ find $\delta>0$ such that when $x>\delta$ we have that $e^{2x}+1>\frac{2}{\varepsilon}$. We can do that because the function $\phi(x)=e^{2x}+1$ tends to $\infty$ as $x\to\infty$.
Then for $x>\delta$ we have that
$$e^{2x}+1>\frac{2}{\varepsilon}\iff\frac{2}{e^{2x}+1}<\varepsilon. $$

Comment: Oh is this really just it. So I was "close"?

Comment: I meant $\delta=\frac{2}{1+e^{2\epsilon}}>0$ and not $\delta=\frac{2}{1+e^{2x}}>0$

Comment: @user879295 well, i don't know. It's up to you to specify into how much detail you want the answer to get into!

Comment: But wouldn't this satisfy the definition and thus be a satisfying proof? Even though it is not in great detail.

Comment: @user879295 you have to decide that. The facts mentioned are correct, the question is, are you happy with that answer or do you feel like you need more details?

Comment: I guess my only confusion would be the part where we start to find the $\delta$. Could you specify how the equality $e^{2x}+1>2/\epsilon$ came about? The RHS is $\delta$, right?

Comment: Excuse the typos as I am new here.